# Jqwidgets and Angular adding more component

Tags: angular, typescript, jqwidget

Gettign This error when trying to add more component in the app created by create-jqwidgets-angular-app utility

> ERROR in ./node_modules/jqwidgets-enter code
>   herescripts/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxgrid.ts Module build failed:
>   Error: /[Project
>   Folder]/node_modules/jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxgrid.ts
>   is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in
>   your tsconfig via the ‘files’ or ‘include’ property.

Answer (score 0):

going through the code of the library and how the CLI works cleared a lot of things to me, so her is my approach to solve the problem:

1. move the two folders `jqwidgets` and `jqwidgets-ts`  into your app folder 
     alongside with your components
2. then you don't need the installed module any more you can delete it

   - update the `tsconfig.ts` and delete the `files[]`
3. Now you can import any component directly to your components and don't forget to include them in your modules

NB: I used create-jqwidgets-angular-app